# Adding ORDER to a SELECT request

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to order my results and I getting a TString Error. Can someone please tell me where or how I can add `ORDER BY date DESC, paymentamount DESC` to this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `Carriers` WHERE fromzip >= '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["from"])."'".$search_string.$search_loadtype;
```

This is what I have tried and it doesnt let me:

```
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `Carriers` WHERE fromzip >= '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["from"])."'".$search_string.$search_loadtype ORDER BY date DESC, paymentamount DESC;
```

Comment: Are you sure that $search_string.$search_loadtype can be appended without space?

Comment: @Bouillou It is present in the original, so it probably works. Definitely doesn't cause a PHP syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `Carriers` WHERE fromzip >= '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["from"])."'".$search_string.$search_loadtype." ORDER BY date DESC, paymentamount DESC";
```

You need to use the (.) to piece string values together. And then you havn't opened the string with quotes...

```
$search_loadtype ORDER BY
```

Becomes

```
$search_loadtype." ORDER BY
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that you missed some quote :

```
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `Carriers` WHERE fromzip >= '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["from"])."'".$search_string." ".$search_loadtype." ORDER BY date DESC, paymentamount DESC";
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me you have the syntax wrong and I can't really know what $search_string and $search_loadtype contains from your code, but give the following a try...

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `Carriers` WHERE fromzip >= '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["from"])."'".$search_string.$search_loadtype . " ORDER BY date DESC, paymentamount DESC;";
```